# Function not working when importing other JS files

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

I'm using a simple script to check when something is in the viewport which then adds a class.

However the script stops working in Webpack when I try to import anything.

Below is basic example of importing which breaks my JS file. It doesn't matter what order I put the import and script etc.

```
window.jQuery = $;

import 'slick-carousel';

$(function ($, win) {
    $.fn.inViewport = function (cb) {
        return this.each(function (i, el) {
            function visPx() {
                var H = $(this).height(),
                    r = el.getBoundingClientRect(), t = r.top, b = r.bottom;
                return cb.call(el, Math.max(0, t > 0 ? H - t : (b < H ? b : H)));
            } visPx();
            $(win).on("resize scroll", visPx);
        });
    };
}(jQuery, window));


$(".preload").inViewport(function (px) {
  if (px) $(this).addClass("is-active");
});
```

If I remove `import 'slick-carousel';` or any of my imports (its not specific to slick-carousel) the script stops working.

[Here is an example](https://codepen.io/Probablybest/pen/eYKBPRN) the viewport script working.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the import in itself might be wrong. Import in javascript is normally an url like:

```
import bar from './bar.js';

bar();
```

Using only import with module name is something you can do in node.

From documentation:
"module-name: The module to import from. The evaluation of the specifier is host-specified. This is often a relative or absolute URL to the .js file containing the module. In Node, extension-less imports often refer to packages in node_modules. Certain bundlers may permit importing files without extensions; check your environment. Only single quoted and double quoted Strings are allowed."

Try adding the import with a relative or absolute url.

If this is not the issue. Please open the console and add the errormessage you get when running with the import.